# GraphQL Schema Definition Language support in graphql-java

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

Hi I'm new to graphql specially graphql-java .

Is there any possible way to use GraphQL Schema Definition Language support in graphql-java? If yes then how it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible since `release 3.0.0`.

```
schema {
    query: QueryType
}

type QueryType {
    hero(episode: Episode): Character
    human(id : String) : Human
    droid(id: ID!): Droid
}
```

You can **convert** an the following **IDL-File** (starWarsSchema.graphqls) to an executable **schema** like this:

```
SchemaParser schemaParser = new SchemaParser();
SchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new SchemaGenerator();

File schemaFile = loadSchema("starWarsSchema.graphqls");

TypeDefinitionRegistry typeRegistry = schemaParser.parse(schemaFile);
RuntimeWiring wiring = buildRuntimeWiring();
GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema = schemaGenerator.makeExecutableSchema(typeRegistry, wiring);
```

Also you have to implement the `buildRuntime` function to **wire your static schema with the resolvers**.

```
RuntimeWiring buildRuntimeWiring() {
    return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
            .scalar(CustomScalar)
            .type("QueryType", typeWiring -> typeWiring
                    .dataFetcher("hero", new StaticDataFetcher(StarWarsData.getArtoo()))
                    .dataFetcher("human", StarWarsData.getHumanDataFetcher())
                    .dataFetcher("droid", StarWarsData.getDroidDataFetcher())
            )
            .build();
}
```

A more detailed example you can find in the [graphql-java documentation](http://graphql-java.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schema.html#idl).

Comment: thanks for your response. I also tried this but the latest jar they provided in maven repository is not supported this . i think this is due to some part of code missing in there latest jar.  the **SchemaGenerator** file is not supported . can you please verify this.

Comment: It is working for the latest release 3.0.0. Make sure you have this version. Perhaps run `mvn clean` explicitly before.

Comment: Does anyone know if you can use comments and descriptions in the idl?